# 403 error forbidden on localhost?

Tags: .htaccess, wamp

I have made a new project on Heroku, with a new ssh key, on an existing repo.

I installed WAMP and configured it to listen to port 8080.

Now when I start the WAMP server and try to access `http://localhost:8080`, I get

> 403 error forbidden. You don't have permission to access / on this server
>   Apache error log:

```
    [Fri Mar 15 23:52:21 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/facebook_apps/account_recevery/floating-inlet-7252/
[Fri Mar 15 23:52:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/facebook_apps/account_recevery/floating-inlet-7252/favicon.ico
```

I've tried to find favicon.ico in that folder, and there is no such file. System and hidden files are shown.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't set up your virtual hosts.

Comment: I would drop a file into that directory (index.html) and see if you can access the file directly (http://localhost:8080/index.html).  I'm pretty sure that the standard WAMP setup prevents browsing an empty directory but I haven't used WAMP in awhile so I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: Also, with such a specific error, I imagine Google, or searching here will turn up some answers.

Comment: And what does heroku have to do with this?

Comment: This happens on my father's laptop, on my pc i have no problem with this. Works on localhost:8080. Tried localhost:8080/index.php (it's a php) and the same error appears

Comment: @uɐɥʇɐᴎ you mean hosts file?

Comment: I don't believe I mentioned a host file.

Comment: Then how can I set up my virtual hosts? Or what do you mean by setting them up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once upon a time I had this issue. So may be it will help you.

Change the file content of `c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` to the following.

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Same setting changes could also apply in `httpd.conf` file as well.

Previously this contains following entry

```
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

remove it from there and restart your server.

Comment: have you restarted your server?

Comment: ok then one more thing you can do it just change same settings for this file as well `httpd.conf`

Comment: I don't know how to thank you! It works now. I've been trying for hours! God bless you!